# Does overriding disqualifies a derived class from being a subtype of its base class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, programming-languages, computer-science, subtype

From Programming Language  Pragmatics, by Scott

> A derived class D has all the members—data and subroutines—of its base
>   class C. As long as D does not hide any of the publicly visible
>   members of C, it makes sense to allow an object of class D to be used
>   in any context that expects  an object of class C: anything we might
>   want to do to an object of class C we can also do to an object of
>   class D. In other words, **a derived class that does not hide any
>   publicly visible members of its base class is a subtype of that base
>   class.**

If `D` overrides a public method of `C`,

- does the overriding method of `D` hide the overridden method of `C`, and
- does the overriding disqualifies `D` from being a subtype of `C`?

What can make a derived class hide a public method of a base class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> does the overriding method of `D` hide the overridden method of `C`

No, overriding is different from hiding, because you are providing a replacement implementation instead of an existing one, not just taking away an implementation without any replacement.

Most object-oriented languages disallow hiding of methods that are designated for overriding (`virtual` of C++, `abstract` and `virtual` of C#). Some languages do not allow hiding at all (Java). This is done precisely to ensure that inheriting `D` from `C` models "is-a" relationship.

> does the overriding disqualifies `D` from being a subtype of `C`?

No, it does not.

Comment: It may be important to note that _subtyping_ typically refers to the definition by Liskov. The definition here by Scott appears to be looser; but according to Liskov, overriding _can_ disqualify a child from being a subtype of its parent if the child violates the parent's contract.

Comment: @jaco. Thanks. What's the difference between the definitions of subtyping by Liskov and by Scott?

Comment: @Tim, Liskov defines subtyping as a semantic relationship; Scott appears to define it as merely a syntactic relationship.

Comment: @jaco thanks. what do you mean specifically by a semantic relationship and a syntactic relationship here for subtyping?

Answer (score 2):

> does the overriding disqualifies D from being a subtype of C?

It depends. If the method in D breaks the contract that the method in C defines, then yes it would disqualify D from being a subtype. If the D method supports the same contract then it doesn't.

I suggest you read up on the Liskov Substitution Principle. Here is the original article she wrote in 1994. It's quite readable.

http://www.csnell.net/computerscience/Liskov_subtypes.pdf

Comment: Thanks. When does "If the method in D breaks the contract that the method in C defines" happen? What can I do to ensure "the D method supports the same contract"?

Comment: First, define the contract. You can sometimes use asserts to ensure the contract is supported, but it depends on the language.